# How To Set A Default Value For Input With Annotation?

Tags: zend-framework2

Let's say I have an input like this:

```
/**
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Hidden")
 * @Annotation\Required(FALSE)
 */
public $flag;
```

How do I set a default value for it? Let's say I want it to be '0' by default.

Comment: `@Annotation\Attributes({"value": 0})` ?

Comment: Thanks, post it as an answer.

Comment: No probs, wasn't 100% sure hence the comment, answer added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Attributes annotation

```
@Annotation\Attributes({"value": 0})
```